# calendarextender not closing when the escape key is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I am using the calendarextender in an asp.net page. It works the way I would expect but after I have the calendar open it won't close automatically when I press the escape key is there something I need to do toget this behavior? The escape key closes the reference [sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspxhttp://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) on asp.net ajax site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the behavior you talk about when I visit the sample site (I'm using Chrome, FWIW). It should be fairly trivial to wire up a keypress event to dismiss the calendar, though.

To clarify, on the sample page, you can execute this code to hide the first calendar:

```
$find("ctl00_SampleContent_defaultCalendarExtender").hide()
```

So wire up a keypress handler to your desired textbox, check for escape and run that code, and voila! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a public page we can see the current behavior at?

Jonas - from what I can tell from the example page he's providing, there's either a configuration problem, or some other conflict. This is why i want to see an example that is experiencing this behavior problem